# google-chrome and chromium file picker don't pick the correct gtk theme

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, chromium, gtk

I still wonder why this happens and does anyone have managed to find any workarounds for this issue. It's very annoying.

File picker or save dialog on google-chrome (111.0.5563.146) and chromium (111.0.5563.64):
[image: chromium]

File picker and save dialog on Firefox, the correct theme one:
[image: firefox]

Both chromium and google-chrome use proper GTK theme on their main windows, but not the file dialogs.
[image: chrome-prefs]

My GTK theme supports GTK3 and GTK4. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 with GNOME 42.5 (X11).

This might not be the first time someone raises this issue up. I found some threads about this also on Xfce etc. Tried out all solutions, but I can't get one of them to work.

Comment: Can confirm this exact issue with both firefox and chromium(both being snap package and Version 112) .Can't replicate the issue on firefox .deb package.I'm running gnome 44

Comment: Mine, both are debian package. I kind of hating snap packages lol. But you can check my latest answer to this thread, not sure if it will work, specially on gnome 44.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue on arch-xfce, only run into many dead ends, It seems to also be a recurring theme that the dialog is the thing dying on us. Another interesting behaviour I noted was that when i click save as something.html I would sometimes (rarely) get a random border. I am using a border theme called "border-only" and that causes the thing to go crazy!

I still have not found an answer.

This is most likely a gtk-chromium end issue tho :(.

I will try downgrading later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most likely there won't be any official fixes for this issue, at least for chrome. They are using `libadwaita` which GNOME applications are also switching to, does not comply with old style GTK theming.

But I found 2 ways to work around it. First one, to enforce it to use the old GTK style by setting up a global environment, `GTK_THEME=<theme_name>`. I found it from [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2030448#p2030448). I am using this way as of now, I put the env key in my `/etc/environment`.

The other one, only if your GTK theme supports and has libadwaita styling. From [this thread](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gtk/issues/155), it is possible to just symlink the styles to GTK4 configuration. For example, if using [flat-remix-gtk](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gtk) theme, can do:
`ln -s /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-LibAdwaita-Red-Dark-Solid/* .config/gtk-4.0/`
I also have tried this and it worked also.

Of course no guarantee both ways will work for you, and also depending on the GTK theme you are using, it might also look broken. So apply it with your own risk. I also need to restart my computer for it to take effect.